# Arduino audio playback without SD card not working?

Tags: if-statement, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I want to create a circuit that plays mainly 2 audio, one when it gets power and another audio by pressing a button. I want to create it without SD card. Library used is PCM.
Here is the code sample.

```
#include <PCM.h>

const unsigned char sample[] PROGMEM = {
  0,6,14,22,30,38,46,54,60,68,74,82,90,98,106,114,112,
  };

void setup()
{
    startPlayback(sample, sizeof(sample));
}

void loop()
{
 
}
```

if anyone knows how to play audio in arduino using button (without sd card)
help me...

Solved : By adding INPUT_PULLUP

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  Learn how to read digital inputs https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/ and do PCM on the Nano https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/pcm/

Comment: Does that sample work for you?   I doubt that these 17 bytes of data produce some recognizable sound. The  original sample has a couple thousand bytes.

Comment: The added sound signal is not actual, when I added the actual sound it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const unsigned char sample2[] PROGMEM = {
    100,96,84,72,60,58,46,34,20,18,4,12,20,38,46,54,62,
};

int inPin = 7;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(inPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

int lastPin = HIGH;  // HIGH means not pressed for Pullup Inputs
void loop()
{
    int pin = digitalRead(inPin);

    if (pin == lastPin)
        return;

    if (pin == HIGH) {
       startPlayback(sample1, sizeof(sample1));
    } else {
       startPlayback(sample2, sizeof(sample2));
    }

    lastPin = pin;
}
```

Comment: you have to trigger the pin status change from LOW to HIGH ( or opposite ) and debounce it ( or wait some time for the sound to finish )

Comment: Tried the answer of @mmixLinus, it not playing both. But when I changed `digitalRead` to `analogRead` and changed pin they both works . But now the problem is that the second sound(play when switch pressed) is playing continuously. Not stopping until switch released.

Comment: modified code to make the button input pullup (so `digitalRead` should work) and handle playing both samples. Start playing 1 if button is pressed, start playing 2 if button is released.

Comment: Thank you, @mmixLinus  and  @datafiddler
Earlier I forget to add the `INPUT_PULLUP` , Now its working.