# Arduino and Processing button does not display one image

Tags: image, button, serialization, arduino, processing

I am doing a project where there is an interaction between Arduino and [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing), thanks to two buttons using the computer serial.

In the first case, I have the Arduino code where each time one of the two buttons is pressed, a series of photos will appear in Processing (the photos are CorBe and CorMal), if the button on pin 8 is pressed **CorBe** photos will appear in a loop and if the one on pin 9 is pressed, **CorMal** photos will appear, these are the first cases, the last two cases of *if else* and *else*, are if the button is not being pressed or if they are pressing both.

The point is that I need that only by pressing the button once and even if it is kept pressed, the **CorBe** or **CorMal** image appears once each time the button is pressed. So the image needs to appear but without erasing the others. Do you have an answer?

Long story short, every time we press button 1, PNG image CorBe needs to appear once. The same with button 2 and image CorMal.

I attach the two codes here:

#### Arduino Code

```cpp
int switchPin = 8;
int switchPinNou = 9;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial communications at a 9600 baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH && digitalRead(9) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("1");
  }

  else if (digitalRead(9) == HIGH && digitalRead(8) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("2");
  }

  else if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH  && digitalRead(9) == HIGH){
    Serial.println("3");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("0");
    }
}
```

#### Processing code

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

PImage img;
PImage img2;
float value = 0;

void setup (){
 String portName = Serial.list()[0]; // Change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
 myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
 myPort.bufferUntil('\n');

 size(1920, 1080);
 background(0);
 img = loadImage("CorBe.png");
 img2 = loadImage("CorMal.png");

 //image(img, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
 //image(img2, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
}

void draw (){
  while (myPort.available() > 0) {
    if (value == 1){
      println("detectado1");
      image(img, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
    }
    if (value == 2){
      println("detectado2");
      image(img2, random(1900), random(1000), 50, 50);
    }
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  value = float(myPort.readStringUntil('\n'));
}
```

Comment: use Bounce2 library in Arduino to handle the buttons. it will do the debouncing and it will report the change of the state of the button instead of the state of the button.

Comment: If you're not into implementing what Juraj said, you can implement a global variable which tracks the state of the button. Only updates it when the button is down or released.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017278/arduino-audio-playback-without-sd-card-not-working-what-to-do-next/70017979#70017979) implements a global variable to track the state of a button.